# renderer.RenderHtml vs. ConfigurationManager

Tags: highcharts

I created a user control identical to the "installation example" provided in the online example; however, as I attempt to run it, it gave me

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

error on line

```
Response.Write(renderer.RenderHtml());
```

I do not know how to remedy this issue. can you provide me with fixes on this issue?

Comment: You are missing the reference to `System.Configuration` in your project.

Comment: Hi @David Chin, Could you add more information about your project and environment?

Comment: thank you. the project's currently targeting .NET framework 4.0, & the project's in web form

Comment: I added the reference "using System.Configuration;" in ascx.cs, as well as "    <add assembly="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51"/>" in web.config, but didn't resolve the issue

Comment: I then used NuGet to do an install with "package-install System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager", but the only version it has available is 4.7, & by force specifying a version via "-version 4.0.1" was not successful

Comment: after installing "System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager 4.7", I ran the code & the code still provide the error indicating that it cannot find 4.0.1

Comment: Could you provide me with a full name and version of the product?

Comment: thank you for your note. the product name's highcharts .net. the tutorial I used to create my first webform chart is from this page (http://dotnet.highcharts.com/Highcharts/Demo/Docs?section=WFFirstChart0)

Comment: if you happened to have a webform project with some demo highcharts pages, please feel free to share this project, & I'll use it as a template for my project instead of trying to create a new project to integrate highcharts

Comment: Hi @David Chin, Please check this example with v7.2: http://dotnet.highcharts.com/downloads/WebForms/WebFormsSamples.zip